# Define which fields are shown in a Django forms.ModelForm list

Tags: django, forms

I want to restrict which fields are shown in the list view of a Django `forms.ModelForm`

I can restrict which fields are shown in the update and create forms but can't work out how to do this for the list view of the form.

My model looks like this:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', blank=True)
```

My view code looks like this:

```
class TeacherListView(GroupRequiredMixin, ListView):
   model = Teacher
   group_required = [u"school_admin"]
   login_url = "/login/"
```

My form code looks like this:

```
class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['name', 'email' ]
```

I am trying to hide the slug field from the list view.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

you will get your answer here.

Comment: Please show your template for your list view.

Comment: @bhattravii yes I looked at that documentation and could not find the answer

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for the prompt! It is of course in the template that I can determine what is shown. Not sure how I missed that!

Comment: @BillNoble Sorry I was not able to understand your question at first, but if you don't want to show particular field you can control that in the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = Teacher
      exclude = ['slug']
```

Comment: you can use exclude for form only.